# how to redirect from www.example.com/Partnerlogin?AuthID=qwer to www.example.com/PartnerLogin.php?AuthID=qwer

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We used to have a java application and in that url used to be http://www.example.com/PartnerLogin?AuthID=qwer but now we have moved to a PHP based application but the URL were given to various partner sites for linking back. The new url should be like http:www.example.com/PartnerLogin.php?AuthID=qwer

I am using following in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^authID=$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^PartnerLogin?authID=(a-z0-9+)$ PartnerLogin.php?authID=$1 [L]
```

please help.

Comment: Is it only ever going to be that one URL being redirected?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} authID=([a-z0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^PartnerLogin$ PartnerLogin.php?authID=%1 [L]
```

Query strings cannot be captured in RewriteRules, and so it needs to be capture in the condition only. Then, you use `%1` in the new URI.